# Are measures that are absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure necessarily regular?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

It is well known that the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, $\mu$ is **regular**; that is, for any Borel set $E$, and any $\epsilon >0$,  there exist an open set $G$ and a closed set $F$ such that $F\subset E\subset G$ and $\mu(G-F)<\epsilon$.

A measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is said to be **absolutely continuous** with respect to Lebesgue measure $\mu$ if there exists a nonnegative integrable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for any measurable set $E$, we have $\nu(E)=\int_{E}f(x)d\mu$.

Question: Is $\nu$ regular? Does there exist a nice counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $\nu$ is regular. For a finite measure $\nu$ on Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$, absolute continuity is [equivalent to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions_2) the statement that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all Borel sets $A$, $\mu(A) < \delta \implies \nu(A) < \epsilon$. Combining this with the regularity of $\mu$, and your assumption that $f$ is integrable, we can deduce the result.